# Node JS : Calling Http Service under Angular JS resolve

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js .

Initially when page is loaded with localhost:3000

index.html is called and redirects to allUsers.html

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
path = require('path'),
index = require('./routes/index');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin_4_angularjs')));

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_4_angularjs/index.html'));
});
module.exports = app;
var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function()
{
        console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

**main.js**

```
// UI Bootstrap
.state('allUsers',
{
        url: "/allUsers.html",
        templateUrl: "views/allUsers.html",
        data:
        {
                pageTitle: 'Users List'
        },
        controller: "allUsersController",
        resolve:
        {
                allUserslist: function($http)
                {
                        return $http.get("/users").then(function(response)
                        {
                                return response.data;
                        })
                }
        }
})
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://xxx.xxx.1.23:27017/RELRE';
var db;
var coll;
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;
  db = database;
});
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
 var collectionInfo = db.collection("UsersInfo");
            collectionInfo.find({}).toArray(function(err, employees) {
               res.status(200).json({'myCollection' : employees});
            });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I get 404 under browser console .

http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)

Could  you please let me know how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You required the router you created, but you need to tell express to use it.

The simplest way would be to add `app.use(index)` to `app.js` after your `GET` route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_4_angularjs/index.html'));
});
app.use(index)
```

Express looks for matching routes top down, so when looking for your `/users` route, it will first check your `/` route and then check the routes the router you included.

However, if you plan to have several routers, I also recommend providing a base path to `app.use` indicating that the router should handle all routes that start with that base path. For example, in your particular case:

```
app.use('/users', index) // may also want to give the router a more meaningful name
```

And then modify you router in `index.js` like so:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) { // within the router, '/users' is now assumed to be the base path
    // Logic for this route
});
```